# Find all occurrences of IP addresses in one list exists within another list of CIDR formatted networks using Python 2.6

Tags: python, ip-address

I have a list of IPv4 addresses (strings).  I also have a list of CIDR formatted networks (strings). Using Python 2.6 I need an **efficient** way to determine what IP addresses in the first list exist within the networks of the second list, noting which network(s) the IP address exists in.

E.g:

```
ip_addresses = ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.1", "127.0.1.1"]
networks = ["127.0.0.0/24", "127.0.0.0/16"]
```

would results in the following:

```
results = {"127.0.0.1": ["127.0.0.0/24", "127.0.0.0/16"],
           "192.168.0.1": [],
           "127.0.1.1": ["127.0.0.0/16"]}
```

What I am thinking to do use the ipaddress module to determine if each IP address exists within one or more of the networks.

```
import ipaddress

ip_addresses = ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.1", "127.0.1.1"]
networks = ["127.0.0.0/24", "127.0.0.0/16"]

ip_networks = []
for network in networks:
    ip_networks.append(ipaddress.ip_network(network))

results = {}
for ip_address in ip_addresses:
    ip = ipaddress.ip_address(ip_address)
    results[ip_address] = []
   
    for network in ip_networks:
        if ip in network:
            results[ip_address].append(ip_network)
```

This may work, but I don't think it would be the most efficient. My network list could be over 100,000 entries. The IP address lists will most likely be less than ten addresses. What is the most efficient method of performing this task?

Comment: You're calling `ipaddress.ip_network(network)` far too often. Just transform `networks` from a list of strings into a list of `IPv4Network` objects before your main loop so that you don't need to re-parse the addresses on every comparison.

Comment: Also, note that it's always best to ensure that the code you've posted is syntactically correct (and ideally, *runnable*). If someone were to try to run your code locally, it would fail because you've written `include` instead of `import`. That means the code you've shown us isn't the code you're actually using, which can lead to inaccurate answers.

Comment: I manually transcribed the code from a large function and made some errors. Corrected my question.

Comment: Why `"127.0.1.1": ["127.0.0.0/16"]` should be in the results? The ip range is not the same, `127.0.1.x` vs `127.0.0.x`

Comment: @Alec_djinn,127.0.0.0/16 includes all IP's from 127.0.0.0 to 127.0.255.255.

Comment: @Calab please, specify how do you decide the IP ranges then, since `127.0.0.0/16` for me is from `127.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.16`. How `127.1.1.1` would be considered? Can you provide more examples for testing edge cases?

Comment: @alec_djinn, check out CIDR notation.

Comment: Why are you only interested in Python 2.6?  It shouldn't be too hard to back port more recent Python code to that

Comment: I don't have control of the machine that is running the code, so I can't control which version of Python is being run. The manager of that system has decided not to upgrade.